# How to access postgraphile route inside the server

Tags: postgresql, graphql, graphql-js, postgraphile

I created **postgraphile** route in my server and in my app.ts there’s this line:
`app.use(postgraphileRoute)`
Now, I want to access this route in my repository.
I’m using *graphql-request* package and I don’t know which url I send when I do `new GraphQLClient()`
I tried to send serverURL/graphql (the way I access it from the client) but it’s not working.
Which url I need to send?

Answer (score 0):

The route defaults to `/graphql` but you can configure it using the `graphqlRoute` property. See also the [docs](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/usage-library/).

```js
const express = require("express");
const { postgraphile } = require("postgraphile");

const app = express();

const postgraphileRoute = postgraphile(
    process.env.DATABASE_URL || "postgres://user:pass@host:5432/dbname",
    "public",
    {
      watchPg: true,
      graphiql: true,
      enhanceGraphiql: true,
      graphqlRoute: '/graphql' // Set to any route you like
    }
);

app.use(postgraphileRoute);

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```